# Is there a wrong way to name Class Based Views in Django?

Tags: django

this is a question about code style and best practices.

In our Django project we have Class Based Views named like this:

urls.py

```
path('project/<int:pk>/clone/', CloneView.as_view(), name='clone'),
path('project/<int:pk>/delete/', ProjectDelete.as_view(), name='project-delete'),
path('project/<int:pk>/optimize/', ProjectOptimize.as_view(), name='project-optimize'),
path('project/<int:pk>/report/', ReportView.as_view(), name='report'),
```

as you can see, some of them we say `MyClassView.as_view()` and in others we just say `MyClass.as_view()`. But I also noticed that in the Documentation they always use the first form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/
Something that also caught my attention is that we never use view in the name, for example: `name=clone-name`.

My question is: is there any noticeable advantage of explicitly saying in the class name that this class is a view? Is it "wrong" not to use it?

I would like to keep our code base consistent.
Thank you all!

Comment: Django has a Coding Style guideline https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/ which basically follows the widely used python pep8 standard for naming convention as well as other constructs. I generally append "Model" for model class names and "View" or "Resource" after the request handler class names just to avoid the confusion and name clashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it really matters whether or not you include the `View` suffix. It's common to include the name in Django projects, but the most important thing it to be consistent across your own project.

One advantage of using the `View` or `Form` suffix is to avoid name clashes. For example `BookView`, `BookForm` and the model `Book` can't clash with each other.

You can avoid clashes by [importing modules instead of objects](https://github.com/octoenergy/conventions/blob/master/python.md#class-naming-conventions), in which case the `Form` and `View` suffixes are not necessary.